# Como identificar en que Fragment me encuentro?

Tags: java, android

Buen día coders tengo un programa donde navego con un `navegationdrawer` y tengo como `fragment` principal  `Fragment_inicio()`. En la aplicacion navego a otros fragments por ejemplo uno llamado `fragment_Reglamento().` Mi pregunta problema es que cuando ejecuto `public void onBackPressed()` identificar si estoy ubicado en el `Fragment_inicio` para salir y de no ser asi regresar a el `Fragment_inicio` aquí mi código.

```
Fragment fragment=null;

public void onBackPressed() {
        DrawerLayout drawer = (DrawerLayout) findViewById(R.id.drawer_layout);
        if (drawer.isDrawerOpen(GravityCompat.START)) {
            drawer.closeDrawer(GravityCompat.START);
        } else { 
            // Esta condicion es la que haria cumplir o identificar si estoy o no en el Fragment_Inicio pero esta mal echa no se como comparar los fragments.
            if (fragment.equals(fragment_Reglamento.class)) {
                    AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(this).setTitle("Salir de la aplicación").setMessage("¿Estas seguro de salir de la aplicación?")
                            .setPositiveButton("Si", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                                @Override
                                public void onClick(DialogInterface dialogInterface, int i) {

                                    try {
                                        this.finalize();
                                        MainActivity.super.onBackPressed();
                                    } catch (Throwable throwable) {
                                        throwable.printStackTrace();
                                    }


                                }
                            }).setNegativeButton("No", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                                @Override
                                public void onClick(DialogInterface dialogInterface, int i) {
                                    dialog.dismiss();
                                }
                            });
                    dialog = builder.create();
                    dialog.show();
                } else {
                    fragment = new Fragment_Inicio();
                    FragmentTransaction fragmentTransaction = getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction();
                    fragmentTransaction.replace(R.id.content_main, fragment);
                    fragmentTransaction.commit(); }
            }
        }
```

Comment: Espero a alguien le sirva esto, saludos

Answer (score 3, accepted):

#### ¿Como identificar en que `Fragment` me encuentro??

La forma más sencilla y correcta de para verificar en que Fragment te encuentras se realiza determinando su tipo, esto mediante el operador de comparación **[instanceof](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se7/html/jls-15.html#jls-15.20.2)**

```
if (fragment instanceof Fragment_Inicio){
    //Es fragment Fragment_Inicio
}else (fragment instanceof Fragment_Reglamento){
     //Es fragment Fragment_Reglamento
}else{
     //Es otro tipo
}
```

Comment: Muchas gracias, me ahorras código eso.

Answer (score 3):

Si estas usando `Toolbar`, esto te puede servir, ya que puedes implementar el `Toolbar` para regresar a tu home, de esta manera:

1) Creas un método para manejo de `Toolbar`, esto para comodidad en caso de que uses mas de 2 `fragments`.

```
public void showToolbar(String tittle, boolean upButton){
        Toolbar toolbar = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.toolbar_op);
        setSupportActionBar(toolbar);
        Objects.requireNonNull(getSupportActionBar()).setTitle(tittle);
        getSupportActionBar().setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(upButton);
    }
```

Teniendo este método puedes controlar el titulo del mismo y su botón de regreso solo con pasarle parámetros adecuados, pasando true en `upButton` se mostrara el `NavigateUp` (la flecha back en el `Toolbar`). Y en `title` simplemente pasas el titulo que quieres que se setee en el momento que haga cambio de `fragment`.

2) Ahora solo queda hacer el cambio de pantalla, así:

```
Fragment2 fragment2 = new Fragment2();
title = getText(R.string.title).toString(); //<-- defines el titulo que quieres para tu toolbar

getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction().replace(R.id.container, fragment2,getClass().getName())
                .setTransition(FragmentTransaction.TRANSIT_FRAGMENT_FADE)
                .addToBackStack(null).commit();
        toolbar.setNavigationIcon(null); <-- acá eliminas el icono del menu drawer en caso de que lo tengas
        showToolbar(title, true); <-- acá seteas el titulo en ese fragment, y a su vez activas el botón de back de la `Toolbar`.
```

3) En este momento te encontraras en el `fragment`, y podrás ver el botón de `back` en el `Toolbar`, solo queda manejar el comportamiento de este botón, como? llamando al método `onSupportNavigateUp`, así:

```
@Override
    public boolean onSupportNavigateUp() {
        // aca volveremos al fragment base o principal 
        Homefragment home = new Homefragment();
        title = getText(R.string.title).toString(); <-- seteas tu titulo inicial
        getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction().replace(R.id.container, home,getClass().getName())
                .setTransition(FragmentTransaction.TRANSIT_FRAGMENT_FADE)
                .addToBackStack(null).commit();
        toggle = new ActionBarDrawerToggle(
                this, drawerLayout, toolbar, R.string.navigation_drawer_open, R.string.navigation_drawer_close); //  para habilitar de nuevo el boton del Drawer en caso que lo tengas
        drawerLayout.addDrawerListener(toggle);
        toggle.syncState();
        showToolbar(title, false);
        return true;
    }
```

Comment: Espero te funcione si usas esta forma, hazme saber cualquier duda, saludos

Comment: No lo estoy haciendo con una `toolbar` u `actionbar` solo es el `navegationdrawer`, pero tu respuesta es util, gracias.

Answer (score 2):

Hola lo que yo hago es que en mi MainActivity esta el metodo  public void onBackPressed()
y ese metodo lo modifico para que me regrese al fragment de inicio te dejo mi codigo esperando que te ayude con tu problema.

```
  @Override
public void onBackPressed() {
    DrawerLayout drawer = (DrawerLayout) findViewById(R.id.drawer_layout);
    if (drawer.isDrawerOpen(GravityCompat.START)) {
        drawer.closeDrawer(GravityCompat.START);
    } else {
        NavigationView navigationView = (NavigationView) findViewById(R.id.nav_view);
        navigationView.setNavigationItemSelectedListener(this);
        FragmentManager fragmentManager = getSupportFragmentManager();
        fragmentManager.beginTransaction().replace(R.id.PON TU FRAGMENTA REGRESAR, new AssistanceFragment()).commit();
        navigationView.setCheckedItem(R.id.CAMBIA ESTA PARTE POR EL ITEM DE TU MENU);
    }
}
```

Comment: No es lo que necesito como tal, ya me respondieron exactamente que necesito. Gracias igual :D

Answer (score 1):

Bueno encontré una forma mas primitiva de resolverlo, creo una variable
`boolean contador=false`

Inicia la actividad cargando el fragment y cambio el contador a True para identificar que estoy en el Fragment_inicio

```
  fragment=new Fragment_Inicio();
  FragmentTransaction fragmentTransaction = getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction();
  contador=true;
  fragmentTransaction.replace(R.id.content_main, fragment).commit();;
```

y si cambio de fragment lo vuelvo `false`

```
   fragment = new Fragment_Inicio();
   FragmentTransaction fragmentTransaction = getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction();
   fragmentTransaction.replace(R.id.content_main, fragment);
   contador=true;
   fragmentTransaction.commit();
```

y ya en la condicion que marque en la pregunta puse esto

```
 if (contador==true){
      <Alertdialog para cerrar la app>
    }else{
           <Regresa a el Fragment_inicio>
         }
```

Comment: en lugar del contador usa "instanceof" para determinar el tipo y por consiguiente el Fragment en el que te encuentras.